# Is it possible to set different font in One UIlabel?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uilabel

I have a string like "This is a good apple." to display on my UIlabel. I would like to set the word "good" with different font. Just look like "This is a ***good*** apple."

Comment: I created an easy class to do this : http://past.is/NDe3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html)... Use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) draw NSAttributedString because UILabel,UITextView doesnot support NSAttributedString...

*PS: if you plan to distribute an iOS6 or newer application, as UILabel now support NSAttributedString, you should use UILabel directly instead of OHAttributedLabel as it is now natively supported by the OS.*

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but I *think* this is obsolete as of iOS 6.0. The original `UILabel` now has an `attributedText` property - see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText

Comment: @MarkAmery I have update my other answer, but forget to update this. Thanks for notify. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208282/advance-search-implementation-in-iphone/4208329#4208329

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to set different / multiple fonts & other properties on Label using NSMutableAttributedString.
Foll is my code:

```
 UIFont *ArialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18.0];
 NSDictionary *arialdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: ArialFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];    
 NSMutableAttributedString *AattrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes: arialdict];

 UIFont *VerdanaFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:12.0];
 NSDictionary *veradnadict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:VerdanaFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
 NSMutableAttributedString *VattrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: newsDate attributes:veradnadict];    
 [VattrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:(NSMakeRange(0, 15))];

 [AattrString appendAttributedString:VattrString];


 lblText.attributedText = AattrString;
```

Note that lblText is the UILabel, outlet as file owner.
One can keep on appending as many NSMutableAttributedString he wants..

Also Note that I've added verdana & arial font in my project & added a plist for the same.

Comment: not working ..[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: ArialFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];  getting error in this line

Comment: @RajeshPillai have you defined the font in first line?

UIFont *ArialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18.0];

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with UILabel. But you could use [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).

An other easier approach could be to use a very small UIWebView. In this you can set the font using html commands.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry but that's not possible with the UILabel implementation, you have two options:

- You can create a UIWebView and put the text HTML formatted
- You can make your own UILabel implementation with that functionallity, with, for example, [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two UILabels, you can have one label with multiple text fonts styles and colors. Here is an example :

```
UILabel *customLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 25)];
customLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self createTwoTextStyleInSingleUILabel:customLbl];// custom method calling
[self.view addSubview:customLbl];
```

Custom Method goes like this :
 Before applying this method,  add QuartzCore framework (needed for CALayers), and CoreText framework(needed for the attributed string.) in your project.

```
  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
  #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>  

- (void)createTwoTextStyleInSingleUILabel: (UILabel *) myLabel{
NSString *firstText = NSLocalizedString(@"First text:", nil);
NSString *secondText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstText,@"Second text"];
CATextLayer *myLabelTextLayer;
/* Create the text layer on demand */
if (!myLabelTextLayer) {
    myLabelTextLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    myLabelTextLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    myLabelTextLayer.wrapped = NO;
    CALayer *layer = myLabel.layer; //assign layer to your UILabel
    myLabelTextLayer.frame = CGRectMake((layer.bounds.size.width-180)/2 + 10, (layer.bounds.size.height-30)/2 + 10, 180, 30);
    myLabelTextLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    myLabelTextLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    [layer addSublayer:myLabelTextLayer];
}
/* Create the attributes (for the attributed string) */
// customizing first string
CGFloat fontSize = 16;
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
CTFontRef ctBoldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);
CGColorRef cgColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            (__bridge id)ctBoldFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                            cgColor, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
CFRelease(ctBoldFont);
 // customizing second string
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
CGColorRef cgSubColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
NSDictionary *subAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)ctFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,cgSubColor, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
CFRelease(ctFont);
/* Create the attributed string (text + attributes) */
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:secondText attributes:attributes];
float lengthOfSecondString = 12.0; // length of second string including blank space inbetween text, space in front , space after text.. Be careful, your  app may crash here if length is beyond the second text length (lengthOfSecondString = text length + blank spaces)
[attrStr addAttributes:subAttributes range:NSMakeRange(firstText.length, lengthOfSecondString)];
// you can add another subattribute in the similar way as above , if you want change the third textstring style
/* Set the attributes string in the text layer :) */
myLabelTextLayer.string = attrStr;
myLabelTextLayer.opacity = 1.0; //to remove blurr effect

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified Akshay's answer and implemented it with Swift:

```
// First part with font size 10
let firstPartInfo = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)]
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "First Part", attributes: firstPartInfo)

// Second part with font size 20
let secondPartInfo = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)]
attributedString.appendAttributedString(
    NSAttributedString(string: "Second Part", attributes: secondPartInfo))

// Lastly set the attributed text
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

No reason to use third party solutions or subclasses.