# iOS - stringWithFormat change part of the text color

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, stringwithformat

I'm pulling in tweets for my application and I want to be able to format my tweets in a certain way and color. For example, here would be a simple tweet...

```
"@somename This is a sample tweet from twitter. - 7 hours ago"
```

Is it possible to take the last part of the string, in this case the "7 hours ago" and change the font / font color?

I'm using `stringWithFormat:` in order to format in this way:

```
tweet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", title, time];
```

But I am unsure if I am able to change the `time` font and color using this code.

Anyone done this before?

**Edit**

I've attempted this using  [AliSoftware's OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel), but I am using ARC and this doesn't seam to be working for me.

Is there a standard "iOS" way of accomplishing this? Maybe using `NSAttributedString` possibly?

Comment: I think that `stringWithFormat`is used to create a new string from more than just a string (integers, floats). As far as I know it has nothing to do with style. Perhaps try [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I think it works fine with ARC. Or you can use two UILabel with different color text. Btw, i think NSAttributedString should be used accompany with Core text. AliSoftware's OHAttributedLabel also implement the core text. You have to import CoreText.framework in your App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Core Text. Maybe the following question would help you [Is it possible to set different font in One UIlabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242786/is-it-possible-to-set-different-font-in-one-uilabel)

You have to import CoreText.framework in your App

Comment: I've added the CoreText.framework to my App. I don't want to use Ali's way of doing it, there has got to be a standard NSAttributeString way of doing it. I just don't know how to structure the code.

Comment: UILabel,UITextView doesnot support NSAttributedStrin. You can try UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString`s don't know about fonts. Have a look at `NSAttributedString` and Core Text. References:

- [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html)
- [NSAttributedString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UILabel with two different color text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3952571/1241690)
- [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417346/1241690)

Answer (score 0):

The font/font color are not inherent attributes of the data type NSString. You could use two separate UILabels, or create a small UIWebView to format the text.